# Connect remote mobile device to chrome devtools on Mac

Tags: debugging, web, google-chrome-devtools

community! Just wanted to ask if is it possible to connect my Android phone(in this case Motorola z2 force Android 7.0) to chrome devtools. The problem is that I'm writing a web site and that it was useable in mobile devices. Everything works fine on all mobiles devices which I have tested, but there is a problem on my Motorola. I want to discover what is the problem, but i can't connect it like in described in google documentation and stackoverflow.

I'm using google chrome version 117.0.5938.132, (x86_64), MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) with macOS Monterey 12.6.8 (21G725)

[image: This is what i see chrome settings]

I switch on developer mode on my device

Connect my device via usb to mac

open chrome://inspect#device

and the device is not showing in list as expected. So I want to debug my ui on motorola to see what causes the problem and looking the ways to do it

Answer (score 1):

I have it the same problem

You have to eneable de Dev mode on chrome and on the device tapping the build in number 7 times like said here [https://en-us.support.motorola.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/160067/~/developer-options](https://en-us.support.motorola.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/160067/%7E/developer-options)

then on the dev options you also have to eneable USB debugging.

after that just have to do as the che developer sayshttps://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging and give the permission to the pc.

hope this resolve your problem